# Python - Browser Automation - MechanicalSoup/ BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, browser, automation, mechanicalsoup

I am attempting to automate a button push that prompts javascript on my own website(godaddy server). I am running a .py from my MAC OS Terminal.

I have found beautiful soup and mechancial soup but only found documentation for parsing text or prefilling forms.
I have attempted mechanical soup code absent any 'form' mention, and merely trying to click a button based on a css selector.

I have played around with this code for a few hours and am not convinced what I want to accomplish is possible. Can anyone confirm this is possible with either of these modules? If not, what is a better tool?

I have just been using the example provided here: https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#first-contact-step-by-step

my code in a function:

```
def updatePrices()
    br = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
    br.open("http://example.com")
    br.get_current_page().find('button', id='exporter_decisionStream')
    br.submit_selected()
updatePrices()
```

Any guidance is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "prompts javascript", but MechanicalSoup doesn't interact with javascript, so that might be the problem. A tool like Selenium is better suited for javascript tasks. This [MechanicalSoup FAQ](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#form-submission-has-no-effect-or-fails) says much the same thing.

Comment: Too clarify, from my understanding a button push in a form, would submit the form. Why can I not, interact with a button, that does not have a form attached to it? My button just calls a javascript function, this function should be executed on the web server and not by the python script, the script just pushes a button, the java should be run on the site as normal; my godaddy server.

Comment: It's a good question! In pure HTML, a form tells the browser where to submit the form data (in this case, "the data" is the name of the button you pressed). MechanicalSoup parses that information from the html and mimics pressing the button. However, if there is no form and javascript that runs when the button is pressed is telling the browser what data to submit, then that's something that MechanicalSoup doesn't support (since it doesn't run javascript).

Comment: Thank you for coming back to this and helping a noob. I will look into Selenium.